# I want to connect my program to image scanner

Tags: python-2.7, image-scanner, pyusb

I want to write program with python which can get input from scanner and save as jpg.
I don't have any idea how to start.
please help.

Comment: Will this be on a Windows computer or Linux?

Comment: I want to use it cross platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, the module you will want to look into is called the [Python TWAIN module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twain/1.0.5), while in Linux (and I think Mac) you should look into [pysane](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysane/2.0.1).

Now that I am digging into this it looks like there is a project called [python-imagescanner](http://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/) that tries to wrap these two approaches into a common library,

From imagescanner's [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/wiki/GettingStarted)

> ```
> Getting access to a scanner device:
>
>  from imagescanner import ImageScanner
>
>  # instantiate the imagescanner obj 
>  iscanner = ImageScanner()
>
>  # get all available devices
>  scanners = iscanner.list_scanners()
>
>  # choose one of the devices
>  scanner = scanners[0]
>
>  # scan your file (returns a PIL object)
>  scanner.scan()
> ```

Comment: Note: Python twain only supports 32-bit Windows.

Comment: It's been a while since I've utilized this answer but doesn't 64 bit Windows include a 32 bit software emulator?

Comment: 64-bit Windows does support running 32-bit software. My guess is that TWAIN interacts with the system at a low enough level that the architecture is a significant detail.

Comment: @JasonSperske I don't understand how to install python-imagescanner on windows with [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/wiki/GettingStarted)

Answer (score 7):

Six years have passed and I came here today looking for the answer to the same question.

Pysane and python-imagescanner in the currently accepted answer are unfortunately no longer active, but after som further searching I found [libinsane](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/libinsane#readme) which seems to be a better option nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Me too, six years later searching and I found this [Capturing an Image from a WIA-compatible Digital Camera](https://sites.tntech.edu/renfro/2009/09/03/capturing-an-image-from-a-wia-compatible-digital-camera/) that really helps. It uses `win32com.client`.

It worked with my scanner Cannon DR-C240.

Code:

```
import win32com.client, time, os

WIA_COM = "WIA.CommonDialog"

WIA_DEVICE_UNSPECIFIED = 0
WIA_DEVICE_CAMERA = 2

WIA_INTENT_UNSPECIFIED = 0

WIA_BIAS_MIN_SIZE = 65536
WIA_BIAS_MAX_QUALITY = 65536

WIA_IMG_FORMAT_PNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

WIA_COMMAND_TAKE_PICTURE="{AF933CAC-ACAD-11D2-A093-00C04F72DC3C}"

def acquire_image_wia():
    wia = win32com.client.Dispatch(WIA_COM) # wia is a CommonDialog object
    dev = wia.ShowSelectDevice()
    for command in dev.Commands:
        if command.CommandID==WIA_COMMAND_TAKE_PICTURE:
            foo=dev.ExecuteCommand(WIA_COMMAND_TAKE_PICTURE)

    i=1
    for item in dev.Items:
        if i==dev.Items.Count:
            image=item.Transfer(WIA_IMG_FORMAT_PNG)
            break
        i=i+1

    fname = 'wia-test.png'
    if os.path.exists(fname):
        os.remove(fname)
    image.SaveFile(fname)

os.chdir("c:/temp")
acquire_image_wia()
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your link, I think it should be this one:
https://sites.tntech.edu/renfro/2009/09/03/capturing-an-image-from-a-wia-compatible-digital-camera/

Answer (score 0):

Just mentioning other approach here in case anyone need simple approach having little code otherwise you can go with @Marcelo's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62271544/11798494).

The idea is to use [Windows Fax and Scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Fax_and_Scan) for scanning document.
Here is the code in python for same.

```
import os
os.system("WFS")
```

It will open Windows Fax and Scan for you. Now you can scan your document.

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Marcelo Gazzola, here's a cleaned version with parameters (tested on windows10, canon lide70):

```
WIA_COM = "WIA.CommonDialog"
WIA_IMG_FORMAT_PNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"


def acquire_image_wia(strDstFilename,rectToScan=(0,0,210,297),nBitsPerPixel=24,nResolution = 300):
    """
    scan an image and save it to disk
    - strDstFilename: pathfilenale of destination
    - rectToScan: rect to grab in milimeters (default: A4)
    - nBitsPerPixel: 1: N&B, 8: gray, 24: color
    - nResolution: resolution in DPI (300, 600, ...)
    """
    wia = win32com.client.Dispatch(WIA_COM) # wia is a CommonDialog object
    dev = wia.ShowSelectDevice()
    scanner = dev.Items[0]
    
    rMagicCoef =  1.17 # looks like a magic, tuned for my canon lide 70. perhaps some DotToInch explanations...
    
    r = []
    for x in rectToScan:
        r.append(int(x*10*rMagicCoef*nResolution/300))
        
    for p in scanner.Properties:
        if p.Name == "Horizontal Start Position":
            p.value = r[0]
        if p.Name == "Vertical Start Position":
            p.value = r[1]
        if p.Name == "Horizontal Extent":
            p.value = r[2]
        if p.Name == "Vertical Extent":
            p.value = r[3]
        if p.Name == "Bits Per Pixel":
            p.value = nBitsPerPixel
        if p.Name == "Horizontal Resolution":
            p.value = nResolution
        if p.Name == "Vertical Resolution":
            p.value = nResolution
            
    image=scanner.Transfer(WIA_IMG_FORMAT_PNG)

    if os.path.exists(strDstFilename):
        os.remove(strDstFilename)
    image.SaveFile(strDstFilename)
```